# Bulk rename reserved filenames in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

Having trouble trying to bulk rename some of the reserved filenames by Windows that are saved into our system. Example 'Con.PDF' - 'Con' is reserved by Windows and by default you cannot save a file with this name, however, we have loads of these in one of our Network shares and we need to get them renamed. I've tried with the Bulk rename utility, CMD and lately with Powershell but cannot get this to work - they all reference that the 'File does not exist'. Is anyone aware of a way we can do this, or amend our current command so that it will work? I'm out of options on this one, here's my Powershell below;

```
$X = 0
$Files = $Null
$Files = Get-Childitem  \\NetworkShare1\Folder1\Folder2 -Recurse -File -Filter *.PDF | Where {(($_.Name -Match 'Con.PDF') -And ($_.Name -NotMatch 'APP SEA'))} | Foreach-object {

#Start ForEach-Object Block
$X = $X + 1
$OldName = $_.name
$NewName = $_.name -replace 'Con',"Con$X"
$FullName = $_.FullName
Rename-Item -LiteralPath "$FullName" -NewName "$NewName" -Force
}
```

The path appears correct when I query each variable and I have this working with other files not named Con, any help greatly appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "OLD-PART-OF-FILE-NAME","NEW-PART-OF-FILE-NAME"}
```

Your going to need to be in the folder that you want to change the file names in.

OLD-PART-OF-FILE-NAME is the part of the file name that you are going to replace. Such as if you are taking the textfil in textfile.txt and replacing it with folderfol, the textfil would go in OLD-PART-OF-FILE-NAME and the folderfol would go in NEW-PART-OF-FILE-NAME.

Comment: Many thanks, I've tried and unfortunately same result - cannot rename as file does not exist though it is clearly there when I query the 'Dir' variable. I might have to look into removing the reserved filename in Windows first.. probably not a good idea but hoping it works.